# Shift + Enter only for desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, textarea, form-submit

I have a React chat application where I use a textarea for the message input because I need multiline support. On mobile this works perfectly because when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it starts a new line. There is a dedicated button to send the message once the user finishes writing their message.

On desktop however, I'd like this to be different. I want the user to have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line. If they only press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I want the message to send.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-shiftenter-and-generate-a-new-line-in-textarea/amp/) which I think I can make work (I haven't added it in yet) but this means for users on their mobile devices, they will be unable to write multiline messages.

How do I go about doing this so that for users on mobile devices, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the textarea will start a new line but for users on mobile, it'll submit the form and they'd need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start a new line?

Comment: How do you define _"mobile"_ and _"desktop"_? By size? By touchscreen? By other features?

Comment: @jabaa Yeah that's a hard question to answer - would it be too much to say mobile is your mobile phones like iPhone and Android phones while desktop would be the rest?

Comment: @dokgu there are android TV devices as well which needs to be considered as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create this functionality by detecting mobile device by it's touch screen feature. Here is working solution [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shift-enter-3wcfjr?file=/src/App.js:0-734)

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const isTouchScren = () => {
    if (window.matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)").matches) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const onKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (
      (isTouchScren() && event.keyCode === 13 && !event.shiftKey) ||
      (event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey)
    ) {
      // next line
      alert("next line");
    } else if (event.keyCode === 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
      // send text
      alert("send text");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <textarea onKeyDown={onKeyPress} rows={4} cols={50}>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
      </textarea>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work. Although I am wondering because I know that there are desktop monitors or even laptops that are touchscreen. But maybe that's okay. Do you think checking the user agent of the browser will be more accurate?

Comment: @dokgu I just tested this code on my brother's touch screen laptop, when I pressed enter it's displays **send text** alert. As for user agent of browsers it can be used, but there are so many browsers you'll have to handle by using regex, or any third party package or your own custom code, so my personal preference is touch screen based on some articles I just read while writing this answer. I suggest searching for posts "how to detect mobile or desktop in javascript".